# Is it possible to check if a class is removed in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I would like to know if a class is removed. something like:

```js
if(".class" is removed) then { get class.object}
```

I need to know it, because I need the object in which the class is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if($("selector").hasClass(".class")) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can be sure that the removal happens via jQuery, hook the method.

```
var _oldremove = jQuery.fn.removeClass;
jQuery.fn.removeClass = function() {
    if( arguments[0] === 'the_class_you_are_looking_for' ) {
        // do something with this === current object
    }

    _oldremove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Be aware that you might need to overwrite more methods, like `.toggleClass`.

Comment: This is most cases causes 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'.

Answer (score 1):

Does .hasClass("someclass") suit your needs?
How will it be removed? Or du you want a trigger for when removing the class?

Comment: if you use .trigger("yourevent") when you remove the class and define a .bind("yourevent",function(){})