# Detect class removal by code I have no control over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function when a class has been removed from an element, **I have no control over when the class is removed.**

Currently I can make it work by using setTimeout, so it's something like:

```
function checkClassRemoval() {
    if (!$('.myElement').hasClass('mySecondClass')) {
        // run function
    }   
}   

setTimeout(checkClassRemoval, 1000);
```

Is there a better way to catch the removal of the class than running a check every second?

Comment: Do you know if the removal of the class is done by jQuery?

Comment: Mutation observers are another approach you can follow for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check if a class is removed in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657972/is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-class-is-removed-in-jquery)

Comment: I disagree @guradio, this is a question. Not an improvement question

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate @rahul_m it's a different question. it's catching the moment when a class has been removed by an external party.

Comment: @Tschallacka OP stated `Is there a better way to catch the removal of the class than running a check every second?` meaning this one works and he wants another option to work on

Comment: @guradio No! This would be hugely off-topic at Code Review! Please read their [guidelines](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making more of such recommendations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) class for this. It allow to subscribe to particular DOM element changes and fire events when this change happens:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!');
    });    
});

var target = document.getElementById('someId');
observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style', 'className'] });
```

For support of this object please refer to [canIuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Comment: I believe attributes: true is redundant when using attributeFilter.

Comment: I needed to specify `"class"` rather than `"className"` on Chrome

Answer (score 3):

You can override addClass/removeClass jQuery function and extend them like this:

```
(function(){
    var nativeMethod= jQuery.fn.addClass;

    jQuery.fn.addClass = function(){
        var result = nativeMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        jQuery(this).trigger('cssClassChanged');
        return result;
    }
})();

//Your code:
$(function(){
    $("#yourElement").bind('cssClassChanged', function(){ 
        console.log("triggered")
    });
});
```